# Error in String Parsing for Calculator - NumberFormatException

Tags: java, android, string, calculator

I am trying to make a calculator app but unfortunately I am getting stuck with parsing the string.

The application takes input and displays it in an `EditText et2`. The calculator does the following job when "equal" key is pressed.

```
et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
s = et2.getText().toString();
int k = 0, i = 0, j = 0, operatorTop = -1, operandTop = -1, end = 0;
float left, right;
float operandStack[] = new float[50];
char operatorStack[] = new char[50];

for (i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

    if (s.charAt(i) == '+' || s.charAt(i) == '-' || s.charAt(i) == '*'
            || s.charAt(i) == '/') {

        if (i == 0 || i == s.length() - 1) {
            break;
        } else {

            left = Float.valueOf(s.substring(k, i - 1));
            operandStack[++operandTop] = left;

            operatorStack[++operatorTop] = s.charAt(i);
            if (operatorStack[operatorTop] == '*'
                    || operatorStack[operatorTop] == '/') {
                for (j = i + 1; j < s.length(); j++) {
                    if (s.charAt(j) == '+' || s.charAt(j) == '-'
                            || s.charAt(j) == '*' || s.charAt(j) == '/')
                        end = j - 1;
                    if (j == s.length() - 1)
                        end = j;

                }
                right = Float.valueOf(s.substring(i + 1, end));
                if (operatorStack[operatorTop] == '*')
                    operandStack[operandTop] = operandStack[operandTop]
                            * right;
                if (operatorStack[operatorTop] == '/')
                    operandStack[operandTop] = operandStack[operandTop]
                            / right;
                operatorTop--;

            }
            k = i++;

        }
    }
}
operandStack[++operandTop] = Float.valueOf(s.substring(k,
        s.length() - 1));
for (i = operatorTop; i > -1; i--) {
    char ch = operatorStack[operatorTop];
    switch (ch) {
    case '+':
        operandStack[operandTop - 1] += operandStack[operandTop];
        operandTop--;
        operatorTop--;
        break;
    case '-':
        operandStack[operandTop - 1] += operandStack[operandTop];
        operandTop--;
        operatorTop--;
        break;

    }
    et1.setText("" + operandStack[operandTop]);
}
```

I get a NumberFormatException error. Here's is the error log :

```
03-09 16:54:07.493: E/AndroidRuntime(362): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-09 16:54:07.493: E/AndroidRuntime(362): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not       execute method of the activity
03-09 16:54:07.493: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
03-09 16:54:07.493: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
03-09 16:54:07.493: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
03-09 16:54:07.493: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-09 16:54:07.493: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-09 16:54:07.493: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-09 16:54:07.493: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-09 16:54:07.493: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-09 16:54:07.493: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-09 16:54:07.493: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-09 16:54:07.493: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-09 16:54:07.493: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-09 16:54:07.493: E/AndroidRuntime(362): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-09 16:54:07.493: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at yadav.sanjay.calculator.CalculatorActivity.click(CalculatorActivity.java:309)
03-09 16:54:07.493: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-09 16:54:07.493: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-09 16:54:07.493: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
03-09 16:54:07.493: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  ... 11 more
03-09 16:54:07.493: E/AndroidRuntime(362): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
03-09 16:54:07.493: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseFloat(FloatingPointParser.java:305)
03-09 16:54:07.493: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:291)
03-09 16:54:07.493: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Float.java:330)
03-09 16:54:07.493: E/AndroidRuntime(362):  ... 15 more
```

Comment: The exception is self explanatory.  You have asked Float.parse() to parse a string which cannot be represented as a float.  Possibly an empty string or something like "1+2".  The string must only contain characters which represent a number which can be a float.  Put a breakpoint on line 309 and inspect the values.

Comment: I know the error type. What I am not able to get is how the string that I am passing is not a number. Upon calculating manually, the string that is been passed is a number. Any operator is not getting passed upon manual calculation.

Comment: first parse your left using ParseInt and type cast it using float

Answer (score 1):

You are try to parse an none Integer value to Integer

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException:
```

Follow the number of line provided in the logcat to correct your mistake

your error must be happened here

```
 left=Float.valueOf(s.substring(k,i-1));
```

other  here

```
 right=Float.valueOf(s.substring(i+1,end));
```

try to do this

```
String leftString=s.substring(k,i-1);
```

and check if the `leftString` can be converted into `float/Integer`

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

So problem is that your `String` has invalid format and cannot be parsed to number. So my suggestion is to use for example **regex** before you will perform parsing:

```
if (yourString.matches("-?[0-9]+")) { // or "[+-]?\\d*(\\.\\d+)?"
   // do your work.
}
```

**Note:** Also add try-catch block to catch `Exception` and make some log about problem(print string value for example).